# CSS Uniformly Sized Cells within a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am creating a website with a popup box containing a table. After hours of trying different combinations with the **table-layout** attribute among others, the table will still not render uniformally.
CSS shown below.

```
#popup {
position: absolute;
height: 50%;
width: 50%;
left: 25%;
top: 25%;
background: white;
border: solid black 1px;
text-align: center;

}


table{
  table-layout: fixed; /* Cells are uniformly sized */;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}
```

The following table is rendered.

[image]

How can I ensure all cells are a uniform size?

Comment: Essentially, you can't without JS or a fixed height. Table ROW heights are sized independently of each other,

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm using JS anyway to add each of the <td> cells. How would I fix this issue with JS?

Comment: The fixed table layout only applies to the columns I believe....

Comment: JS solution, get the full table height, divide by the number of rows, apply the height to the rows...

Answer (score -1):

I believe you'd be much better off making use of CSS Grid for this kind of layout.

For learning CSS Grid I recommend the [Grid Garden](https://cssgridgarden.com/) and [Grid Critters](https://gridcritters.com/) (the latter does have a fee) gamified tutorials.  Both companies also have flexbox tutorials too (Flexbox Froggy and Flexbox Zombies, both free)

Anyway, here's an executable reproduction of your layout using Grid:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/14/22/42/milky-way-2750627_960_720.jpg") ;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.grid {
  align-self: stretch;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.heading, .col-1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.heading {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.col-1 {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.blank {
  grid-column: 2 / span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <h2>Date</h2>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="heading">
      H103
    </div>
    <div class="blank"></div>
    <div class="col-1">Period 1</div>
    <div class="col-1">Period 2</div>
    <div class="col-1">Period 3</div>
    <div class="col-1">Period 4</div>
    <div class="heading">
      H104
    </div>
    <div class="blank"></div>
    <div class="col-1">Period 1</div>
    <div class="col-1">Period 2</div>
    <div class="col-1">Period 3</div>
    <div class="col-1">Period 4</div>

    <div class="heading">
      H105
    </div>
    <div class="blank"></div>
    <div class="col-1">Period 1</div>
    <div class="col-1">Period 2</div>
    <div class="col-1">Period 3</div>
    <div class="col-1">Period 4</div>
    <div class="heading">
      H107
    </div>
    <div class="blank"></div>
    <div class="col-1">Period 1</div>
    <div class="col-1">Period 2</div>
    <div class="col-1">Period 3</div>
    <div class="col-1">Period 4</div>

  </div>
</div>
```